# How to track increase of number attribute in given time range with expressjs and mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm using Express and Mongoose/Mongodb to create an API.
I have a model in mongoose representing apps(basic schema given below).

```
/* In apps collection */
app = { 
_id: ObjectID,
createdAt: Date,
name: String,
numberOfDownloads: Number,
downloadLink: String
/* More object data */
}
```

When an app is downloaded, the **numberOfDownloads** attribute is incremented and this functionality already exists. How do I keep track of apps whose **numberOfDownloads** attribute has increased the most in a given time range? Let's say in the last 24 hours.

One way that I've thought of is to have a background job running and saving in a different collection named **indexedAppDownloads** every few hours objects with **appId** and **numberOfDownloads** attributes. And another collection named **popularApps** having only the most popular apps.

```
/* In indexedAppDownloads collection */
indexedAppDownload = {
appId: ObjectId,
_id: ObjectId,
createdAt: Date,
numberOfDownloads: Number
}
```

So the current **numberOfDownloads** attribute in **apps** collection is checked against that in the **indexedAppDownloads** collection using appId to find the app and where the difference is highest, apps are selected and stored in the **popularApps** collection after deleting everything there. This is done every few hours or once in a given time range.

Is there a better approach to this than what I plan to do?